# NBackup x Firebird - The application failed to initialize properly (0xc000007b)

Tags: firebird

I'm trying to run nBackup Firebird through command line below

```
C:\nbackup.exe -U sysdba -P masterkey -B 0 C:\nomedobanco.FDB C:\nomedobackup.TMPNBK
```

but it appears to me the following error

```
The application failed to initialize properly (0xc000007b). Click OK to close the application.
```

What to do? Someone has gone through something similar?

Comment: 1) Which version of Firebird, 2) have you tried reinstalling Firebird?

Comment: 0xc000007b = STATUS_INVALID_IMAGE_FORMAT. So you mixed 32 and 64Bit files. reinstall Firebird.